# `[Exception] DateTime::__construct(): `It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php, exception, timezone, codeception

I 'm  using codeception (bdd) making test but gives error

```
[Exception]                                                                                                
  DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You   are *required* to   
  use the date.timezone setting 
 or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used
```

any of those
  methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.

We selected `Europe/Helsinki` for `EEST/3.0/DST` instead ;

can i do?

Comment: Read the error, apply what it says. If that’s not working, could you please show your code?

Comment: Set `date.timezone` in your php.ini to your local/desired time zone.

Comment: I'm living Turkey . I  try Europe/Istanbul.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');` before running this code.

For other timezones, check [PHP Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: I did use Europe/Istanbul. the error code does not. console running

Comment: You need to write this line before run the troublesome lines. If it still  goes on, share the code block so we can help you.

Comment: I did use this example.  http://codeception.com/quickstart . I get an error when I run the console

Comment: @KemalKarakaş - That site has a lot of examples, which one did you try?  And what was the error you got?

Comment: @MAttJohnson error is `code` [Exception]                                                                                                
  DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to   
  use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those   
  methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We se  
  lected 'Europe/Helsinki' for 'EEST/3.0/DST' instead       `code`

Answer (score 8):

This is an issue with your PHP configuration, not with Codeception itself.

In the command line run `$ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`, and then navigate to that folder. Edit php.ini and find the line that says `date.timezone` and set it to `date.timezone = "Europe/Helsinki"`